# Django can't import external libraries

Tags: python, django, import, module, shared-libraries

So I am using Django version 2.26, and Python 3.7.3. Whenever I try to import or include an external library in my app within my project (specifically background_task in this case, but this error works with celery and a lot of others), it says 'no module named' even though it is installed. And when I run the Django shell and import it works.

[image: installed apps]
[image: error]
[image: install]

My settings.py file looks like this:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = # removed here

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*',
]
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'background_task',

    'projects', 
    'blog',
    'landingpage',
    'workspace',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["portfolio/templates/"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/workspace/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have installed background_tasks in an environment which is not being used when you start django.

This is why it's recommended to isolate projects in virtual environments. Using virtualenvironments is good because you can isolate requirements between projects and reduce the risk of dependency conflicts.

Once you have installed a virtualenvironment for the project, install all the necessary requirements (put them in a requirements file then run `pip -r requirements.txt`) and start django from the same virtual environment.

You can read more about virtual environments [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: So I installed a virtualenv and used that to install the required packages, I then ran the Django project in the virtualenv and am still getting the same problem

Comment: I'm afraid it's something that you are doing. Are you sure you activated the virtualenv and installed the packages within the virtualenv _and_ tried to start django from within the virtualenv? Be aware that activating a virtual environment does not maintian across terminal windows/sessions. 

I have just done the following to test:

Made a new python 3.7.3 virtual environment // installed django 2.2.7 // install django-background-tasks // added background_tasks to settings.py // started shell and imported background tasks.